# How do you connect to an LDAP server using node-oracledb?

Tags: oracle, ldap, node-oracledb

I have a database that I can connect to using jdbc using the string "jdbc:oracle:thin@ldap://SERVER_NAME:1234/SERVICE,cn=OracleContext,dc-world".

However, when I use node-oracledb, this connection string does not work, presumably because Node doesn't use jdbc.  What connection string could I use to connect to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "Easy Connect" syntax available for LDAP so you will need
to configure ldap.ora and sqlnet.ora files and use a non-Easy Connect
string alias in node-oracledb (or in other tools like SQL*Plus, PHP OCI8, Python cx_Oracle, Golang godror etc).

I'm told (!) the steps are:

1. Invoke netca -> Directory Usage
2. Configure naming to use LDAP by netca->Naming Methods Configuration.  This sets up sqlnet.ora for name lookup.
3. run netmgr to setup the entry in ldap or Enterprise Manager to setup ldap.
4. Copy those files to a subdirectory on the machine where you run Node.js, and set TNS_ADMIN to the directory containing the files.  With Instant Client you can put it in the `network\admin` subdirectory under the Instant Client libraries.  See the manaul entry [Optional Oracle Net Configuration](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#tnsadmin)
5. Set node-oracledb's connectString to the connect alias configured in 3, e.g. "orcl"

Comment: netca seems to be a linux only tool and unfortunately I'm running windows. is there anyway you or someone could post a sample generated by these tools?  that would be very helpful.  Also, this seems to be a common problem when migrating from Java to node.  Has oracle said anything about supporting the LDAP style connection strings?

Comment: netca is not linux only, works on windows. install oracle database and it comes with it by default.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get an ldap connection to work, I had to do the following:

In the network/admin folder of the oracle client add (These were provided by my db admin, [but there are examples here:](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1212#issuecomment-591940440)):

- LDAP.ORA
- sqlnet.ora

And then the connectString is just the service name and nothing else. So, using the original example `jdbc:oracle:thin@ldap://SERVER_NAME:1234/SERVICE,cn=OracleContext,dc-world` the connectString would just be `SERVICE`

Comment: This should be the correct answer, thanks for the detailed instructions.